# ForEach-Object Powershell write error per iteration

Tags: powershell, foreach

Sorry for the bad title, but I'm having trouble describing this with brevity.

I wrote a Powershell script that sends an email with a specific attachment to a list of users in a CSV. The script does what it is supposed to do. I am importing a CSV and piping it to ForEach-Object. Ex:

```
Import-Csv $csvFile | ForEach-Object{Send-MailMessage -To $($_.email) -Attachments $attachPath$($_.attachment) -SmtpServer $mailServer -Credential $credential -UseSsl $subject -Port $mailServerPort -Body "Hello $($_.name),$body" -From $sender -BodyAsHtml }
```

Again, this works as intended. The issue I have is that if there is an error I have no idea which iteration of the loop it occurred in.

I've figured out how to pipe the errors to a file using:

```
Import-Csv $csvFile | ForEach-Object{Send-MailMessage -To $($_.email) -Attachments $attachPath$($_.attachment) -SmtpServer $mailServer -Credential $credential -UseSsl $subject -Port $mailServerPort -Body "Hello $($_.name),$body" -From $sender -BodyAsHtml } 2>> error.txt
```

However, this does not give me any specific information on which  line of the CSV it failed on.

According to Microsoft's documentation for the Send-MailMessage Cmdlet it does not provide any output.

I'd be happy if it would just print the $_.email along with the error to error.txt but everything I've tried doesn't work.

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I swear, I only post try/catch responses here now.

So, the way around this problem is to take your process, add `-ErrorAction STOP` and place the whole bit of code within a try/catch block.  This will allow us to try your first command, if we hit an error, then we'll run the bit of code within the catch block.  We'll just put a better Write-Error message here to give you some better output.  And we'll also store of the one's with errors in a variable we can output at the end.

```
$errors = @()

Import-Csv $csvFile | ForEach-Object{
    try {Send-MailMessage -To $($_.email) -Attachments $attachPath$($_.attachment) `
            -SmtpServer $mailServer -Credential $credential -UseSsl $subject `
            -Port $mailServerPort -Body "Hello $($_.name),$body" -From $sender -BodyAsHtml -ErrorAction Stop}
  catch {Write-Error "Unable to send e-mail for this object $_.email" 
        $errors += $_.Email}  
    }

    Write-output "Unable to send e-mails for the following users"
    $errors
```

Give it a shot, and let me know how it works for you.

Comment: Thanks so much. As written, it runs fine when there are no errors. When I introduce an error (I gave a bad email address on one of the csv lines) I get:  `Unable to send e-mail for this object The specified string is not in the form
required for an e-mail address..email
At line:1 char:1
+ C:\ps\key-mail\keys-mail-test.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,keys-mail-test.ps1`  Unable to send e-mails for the following users

Comment: Cool, that's better than no output.  Another thing you could do is modify that $catch statement and add the current error message to $errors.  The code for that, is as follows `$errors += $error[0]` also, you'll want to comment out the Write-Error line I provided.  These changes will grab the most recent error and collect that in $errors.  Then you'll be able to capture the output from Send-Mailmessage.